# Error: the number of weights does not match the population

Tags: python

I am currently developing a mini game where you need to get characters from boxes, and I created a mechanism that does not allow you to get characters if you have them all, but I always get an error

Here's example:

```py
reward_list = ["Gold", "Character", "Gems", "Nothing"]
unlocked_characters = []

if reward[0] == "Character" and len(unlocked_characters) == 39:
   reward_list.pop(0)
   reward = choices(reward_list, weights=[0.5, 0.18, 0.05], k=1)
```

And it gives me an error: The number of weights does not match the population

Can you tell me what I did wrong and how to solve this error

Comment: Could you please say if `reward.list`, `reward` and `reward_list` are different or if there are just errors? Additionally, is the only index possible for `"Character"` 0?

Comment: reward.list and reward_list it's the same thing, it's just that I accidentally wrote the question with a dot, but the reward [0] is sent to the randomizer which works fine

Comment: The way the code is written, `reward` shouldn't exist when you are entering the `if` though? Or is it defined higher? In this case it would be interesting to know how...   Are you sure you want to remove `"Gold"` from `reward_list` if `result[0] == "Character"`?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=choices#random.choices): _"If a weights sequence is supplied, it must be the same length as the population sequence"_ In other words you cannot specify 3 weight values for a population sequnce shorter or longer that 3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to generate a reward that can be either `"Gold"`, `"Character"`, `"Gems"` or `"Nothing"`, excepted if the player already has all the characters (can be checked by verifying if `len(unlocked_characters) == 39`).

```py
from random import choices

reward_list = ["Gold", "Character", "Gems", "Nothing"]
unlocked_characters = []

reward = choices(reward_list, weights=[0.5, 0.18, 0.05, 1-(0.5+0.18+0.05)], k=1)
if len(unlocked_characters) == 39: # if the player has all the characters
    while reward == "Character": # then we will re-generate a reward until it isn't a character
        reward = choices(reward_list, weights=[0.5, 0.18, 0.05, 1-(0.5+0.18+0.05)], k=1)

print(reward)
```

As explained in the comments of the code, we will generate new rewards until it isn't a character, in the eventuality that the player has them all and that the first reward is indeed a character.